# Change the first column width of the table

Tags: tables, margins

I have a problem with the width of the first column of the following table:

[image: 1]

The desired result is:

[image: 2]

Edit:
it's possible to apply at this code?

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|lll}
  \hline
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}
  \\
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}URL pagina scansionata}
  &
  ciao
  \\  \hline
  \hline
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}
  \\
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}Indirizzo ip utente}
  &
  cioa

   \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: some code you have not shown has made the column wide, you need to remove that code so it is natural width.

Answer (score 1):

if you try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{yellow!65}}l R{10cm}}
    \hline
    URL pagina scansionata & ciao \\
    \hline \hline
    Indirizzo ip utente & cioa \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

the result is this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- you provide only code snippet, not complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), so, about preamble you left us guessing ...
- your code snippet is not consistent. Any array (table, matrix, etz) had to has so many columns as it has defined in table preamble.

  In your case you define four: `X|lll` but used only two. You should add them in table body regardless that you not use them, however
- empty columns take space for only two `\tabcolsep`
- from provided image one can conclude (as *BrainOntube* do), that actually you like to have only two columns where the width of the first is accommodated to cells content and the second occupy the rest of table width as suggest *BrainOntube* in his/her answer
- it is not clear, why you use `multirow`. The solution of *BrainOntube* isn't sufficient?

MWE which consider your code sniped (so far as it is sensible) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
    \hline
\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}  &             \\
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}URL pagina scansionata}
                          &    ciao    \\
    \hline
    \hline
\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}  &           \\
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}Indirizzo ip utente}
                          &    cioa    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]